# How to create a png with transparent background in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, png, svg

Is it possible? A PNG usually consumes less storage space compared to an SVG. Sometimes I need small sized images in sites like Launchpad.

When I simply save as PNG, the background remains white, not transparent.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

That's actually Inkscape's default.

- Open *File* → *Document Properties* and click the *Background colour* option. Make sure the alpha channel is `0` as so:

  [image]
- Go to *File* → *Export Bitmap (Shift+Ctrl+E)* and save the file with a .png extension.

You're done.

Comment: I always tried to "save as" .png and it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, "save as" did not apply the Alpha 0 settings as all we guess...

Comment: If you are exporting something that clearly has no background, for example one or more paths, but your export still has a background color, make sure to check "hide all except selected" in the export options

Answer (score 5):

Shortcut, at least in MS Windows, is (Shift+Ctrl+E).

[image]

*Inkscape 0.91*

Comment: It adds the view of a specific version, and the keyboard shortcut. I would have just appended it to the accepted answer, but I have been denied with similar amounts of info in the past. In which case, I was told that it warranted its own answer. Also, I did bump the accepted answer for pointing me in the correct direction, but it wasn't exactly right for the version I am using.

Comment: It works on windows